# Bootstrapping with more than one random effect

Tags: mixed-model, bootstrap, crossed-random-effects

Consider an experiment with $m$ subjects and $n$ words. Every subject rates every word, producing an $(m \times n)$ data matrix $\hat{X}$. I am interested in forming a confidence interval around $f(\hat{X})$ where $f$ is some arbitrary scalar function. I'd like this confidence interval to take into account both the sampling error that comes from the random choice of subjects and the sampling error that comes from the random choice of the words.

What I'm inclined to do is to bootstrap both subjects and words: On each bootstrap iteration, randomly resample the words (with replacement) and the same for subjects (using the same set of resampled words for all resampled subjects). This generates a resampled data matrix $X^\ast_i$, and a bootstrap estimate $f(X^\ast_i)$. The vector of bootstrap estimates (e.g., 10,000 of them) is then used to form a bootstrap confidence interval (e.g., percentile bootstrap) as if these estimates were standard, single-factor bootstrap estimates.

1. Is this legit or am I violating some implicit assumption of the bootstrap?
2. Is there a more principled way of dealing with this problem?
3. Is there any R package that implements such a procedure? I can easily write the resampling code but calculating advanced bootstrap intervals (e.g., BCa) isn't trivial. `boot` seems to assume a single random effect.

Comment: Do you have any fixed effects?

Comment: $f(\cdot)$ measures the performance difference between two models predicting the ratings. You can think about the two models as a fixed effect.

Comment: Also, what you’re proposing seems like it would be a permutation. Maybe I’m reading it wrong, but it sure looks like you could wind up with Ronald evaluating “fissure” when only other subjects evaluated that word.

Comment: In the experiment, each subject evaluated all of the words, and the bootstrap resampling respects that (for resampled words and subjects). You can think about $X^\star$ as produced by resampling the rows and then resampling the columns (or vice versa) of $X$. Both matrices are dense (i.e., no missing values).

Comment: It seems you're assuming that ratings given to each word are independent. But, is that really the case? It seems possible that subjects might rate words differently depending on the order they're presented in, the overall collection of other words, the history of recently presented words, etc.

Comment: @user20160 That's true, the bootstrap does neglect the order (although I'm willing to live with that). What would be your alternative?

Comment: Have you looked into the different options available through the bootMer() function? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lme4/versions/1.1-21/topics/bootMer

Comment: The procedure looks legit to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in this case it is recommended to do a parametric bootstrap: the mixed effect model gives you an estimate of the variance of the effects of words and subjects, so you can generate new random deviates from their distribution (thus without actually resampling the estimated values). It is not difficult to write the code yourself, but if you used the `lme4` package to estimate the model then I think you should be able to do it via the function [`bootMer`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lme4/versions/1.1-21/topics/bootMer). If I understood correctly your problem, you could just write a wrapper function that computes predicted values $X^*$ from the bootstrapped model and calculate the function $f(X^*)$; and pass it to `bootMer`. Once you have a boostrapped distribution for $f(X^*)$ you can use any methods to calculate a confidence interval (e.g. percentile). If you are interested in BCa intervals I have some code that calculate that [here](https://github.com/mattelisi/mlisi/blob/master/R/bootmeanci.R) (it is part of a small package that contains my frequently used custom functions available [here](https://github.com/mattelisi/mlisi))